# Iterating through a slice and resetting the index - golang

Tags: go, slice

I am iterating through a slice in golang and picking off elements one by one. The problem I am having is that after I remove an item I should either reset the index or start from the beginning but I'm not sure how.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2, 3, 7, 16, 22, 17, 42}
    fmt.Println("We will start out with", x)

    for i, v := range x {
        fmt.Println("The current value is", v)
        x = append(x[:i], x[i+1:]...)
        fmt.Println("And after it is removed, we get", x)
    }
}
```

Will Return the following:

```
We will start out with [1 2 3 7 16 22 17 42]
The current value is 1
And after it is removed, we get [2 3 7 16 22 17 42]
The current value is 3
And after it is removed, we get [2 7 16 22 17 42]
The current value is 16
And after it is removed, we get [2 7 22 17 42]
The current value is 17
And after it is removed, we get [2 7 22 42]
The current value is 42
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox337422483/main.go:13 +0x460
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this? 
I immediately thing i-- or i = i-1 coming from Python.

Comment: Idiomatically is to not modify the collection you're iterating over, but build a new one iteratively.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/6_91N2LWQA if you must, but you really don't need to repeatedly copy all the slice elements like that.

Comment: Or, do you just want to pop off the first element in each iteration? https://play.golang.org/p/WgMpEGpZQV

Comment: Thanks for the responses - much better understanding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to create a copy. But also it can be done without if you change `range` part:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2, 3, 7, 16, 22, 17, 42}
    fmt.Println("We will start out with", x)

    for i := 0; i < len(x);  {
        fmt.Println("The current value is", x[i])
        x = append(x[:i], x[i+1:]...)
        fmt.Println("And after it is removed, we get", x)
    }
}
```